# In Cryptonomicon, why didn't the Nipponese government dig up Golgotha after the war?

Tags: cryptonomicon

The Nipponese, fearing imminent defeat, bury most of their gold in a mountain in the Philippines. Presumably, they do it to prevent the Allies from getting hold of it.

What was their plan for recovering it? Why didn't they? There must have been someone at the Nipponese government who knew the location of Golgotha. Why don't they show up?

Comment: Your last assertion is questionable. All who knew might have died in desperate *banzai* charges, or tried and sentenced for war crimes, or simply gone into private life rather than government. They might have answered a direct question from their Emperor, but not from the post-war government installed by the Americans.

Comment: As I remember, the post war government was mostly the old government obeying the Americans, and then soon afterwards a new government democratically elected by the Japanese people.